# Multiple asynchronous calls (javascript facebook api) fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, jquery-mobile

I am using `Facebooks Javascript API` , in my *jquery mobile website* , in order to download albums and photos from a facebook public page and present them to my website.

The API is really straightforward on how things are done and i made everything working fairly easily.

**What i have done so far and IS working**

When a user hits a button i load a page , where the javascript FB API is called and dynamically generate a list of all the albums of a specific facebook page , with all the photos etc. This works great. When the API is called it fetches only 25 albums and when i have more albums to fetch , i have a "More Albums" button which the user hits to make another call to the API and fetch more albums. That works great too...

**The Problem**

My problem appeared , when i decided that i want to have 2 different facebook pages that i would like to import albums/photos from. So i made a horizontal button with 2 options (facebook page 1 , facebook page 2) , made the navBar persistant and when i hit one of the buttons i need an API call to be made and get the albums of each page. THIS sadly doesnt work... When i make a call to one of the 2 pages , everything works. Even the "more albums" button works. But when i navigate to the other facebook page , the call to the api doesnt work... I cant understand why... The "More Albums" button works , that means i can make multiple calls to the api. But why when i navigate with ajax , to the other page on my jquery mobile site , the call cant be completed? I put an alert inside the javascript file and i see it , that means that the code is called. But when i put the alert inside the actual call to the api , i cant see anything alerted.... I guess that means that for some reason the call is blocked...

Any ideas what might be happening here?

My javascript for one of the 2 albums looks like this :

```
$('#photosNJ').on("pageshow", function() {
        var albumPhotos = new Array();
        var albumThumbnails = new Array();
        var x=0;
        var next;
        var times=0;
        var dataLength=0;

        // start the entire process
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            // init the FB JS SDK 
            FB.init({
                appId      : '564984346887426',                                                  // App ID from the app dashboard
                channelUrl : 'channel.html',                                                     // Channel file for x-domain comms
                status     : true,                                                               // Check Facebook Login status
                xfbml      : true                                                                // Look for social plugins on the page
            });
            $.mobile.loading("show");
            FB.api('169070991963/albums', checkForErrorFirst(getAlbums));
            //$.mobile.loading("hide"); 

        }


        // checkForErrorFirst wraps your function around the error checking code first
        // if there is no response, then your code will not be called
        // this allows you to just write the juicy working code 
        // and not worry about error checking
        function checkForErrorFirst(myFunc) {
            return function(response) { 
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert("Error !");
                } else {
                    myFunc(response);
                }
            };  
        }

        function getAlbums(response) {
            //if statement checks , if there are any more albums to load. If not we disable the "More Albums" button.
            if(response.paging.next == undefined) $("#loadMoreAlbums").parent().hide();
            //variable next holds the URL for the next 25(or less) albums
            next = response.paging.cursors.after;
            dataLength = response.data.length + dataLength;
            for (var i=0; i < response.data.length; ++i) {
                processAlbum(response.data[i], i+x);
            }
            x = x+i;
            console.log(x);
        }


        function processAlbum(album, i) {
            FB.api(album.id + "/photos?limit=300", checkForErrorFirst(populateAlbum(album, i)));
        }


        function populateAlbum(album, i) {
            return function(response) {
                for (var k=0; k < response.data.length; ++k){ 
                    albumThumbnails[i] =  albumThumbnails[i]||[];
                    albumThumbnails[i][k] = response.data[k].picture;
                    albumPhotos[i] = albumPhotos[i]||[];
                    albumPhotos[i][k] = response.data[k].source;
                }
                // now that we've populated the album thumbnails and photos, we can render the album
                FB.api(album.cover_photo, checkForErrorFirst(renderAlbum(album, i)));
            };
        }

        function renderAlbum(album, i) {
            times++;
            if(times == dataLength) $.mobile.loading("hide");
            return function(response) {
                var albumName = album.name;
                var albumCover = album.cover_photo;
                var albumId = album.id;
                var numberOfPhotos = album.count;

               // render photos
               $(".albums").append('<li>'+
               '<a href="#Gallery' + i + '"' + 'data-transition="slidedown">'+
               '<img src= "' + response.picture + '"  />'+
               '<h2>' + albumName + '</h2>'+
               '<p>' + "Number of Photos:  " + numberOfPhotos +'</p>'+
               '</a>'+
               '</li>').listview('refresh');

               $("#photosNJ").after('<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id=Gallery'+ i +
               ' class="gallery-page"' + ' data-url="Gallery' + i + '"> ' +
               ' <div data-role="header"><h1>Gallery</h1></div> ' + ' <div data-role="content"> ' +
               ' <ul class="gallery"></ul> ' + ' </div> ' +
               ' </div> ');

               for(var n=0; n < albumPhotos[i].length; n++) {
                    $('#Gallery' + i + ' .gallery').append('<li><a href="' + albumPhotos[i][n] 
                    + '"  rel="external"><img src="' +  albumThumbnails[i][n] + '"' + '/> </a> </li>');
               }

               //adding a "More Photos" button inside every album
               // $('#Gallery' + i + ' .gallery').after('<button type="button" class="loadMorePhotos">More Photos...</button>');
             };



        }

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        //"More Albums" button
        $("#loadMoreAlbums").click(function(){
            // start the entire process
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            // init the FB JS SDK 
            FB.init({
                appId      : '564984346887426',                                  // App ID from the app dashboard
                channelUrl : 'channel.html',                                     // Channel file for x-domain comms
                status     : true,                                               // Check Facebook Login status
                xfbml      : true                                                // Look for social plugins on the page
            });
            }
            //when the "More Albums" button is pressed , we make a call at the API for the next 25(or less) albums , using the "next" URL
            $.mobile.loading("show");
            FB.api('169070991963/albums?after=' + next +"'", checkForErrorFirst(getAlbums));
        });
});
```

You can see the call to the api , the dynamic creation of the html page to show the albums in a listview , the population of the albums with photos , the more albums button etc... The javascript for my other facebook page is IDENTICAL and only the page ID changes. At this point , i want to point out that if i load the other page first and then this one AGAIN the second call is the one that is not working. That means that i dont have a specific problem with one of the albums , rather than a problem that the second call NEVER runs.

Here is the html page just in case you need to see what i am exactly trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/EspacioJoven.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" /> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/custom.css" />

    <!--Used by PhotoSwipe Plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="photoSwipe/klass.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="photoSwipe/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='photoSwipe/photoSwipeCall.js'></script>      
    <link href="photoSwipe/jquery-mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="photoSwipe/photoswipe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--Used by PhotoSwipe Plugin --> 

    <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/createFb2.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/createFb.js'></script>

</head> 
<body>  
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme = "a" >
    <div data-role="content">   
        <h2 id="banner">Joven Mobile</h2>
        <div class="main_menu">
            <ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#espaJoven"><img src="themes/icons/news.png" alt="Information" class="ui-li-icon">Es Joven</a></li>
                <li><a href="#noJoven"><img src="themes/icons/research.png" alt="Information" class="ui-li-icon">La Noche es Joven</a></li>
                <li><a href="#photosNJ"><img src="themes/icons/staff.png" alt="Information" class="ui-li-icon">Multimedia</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sanrJoven"><img src="themes/icons/students.png" alt="Information" class="ui-li-icon">Sar Joven</a></li>
            </ul>       
        </div> <!-- /main_menu -->
    </div> <!-- /content -->
</div> <!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="photosNJ" data-theme="a" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">
    <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/createFbAlbums.js'></script> -->
    <div data-role="header" data-id="fixedNav" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Application Title</h1>
        <a href="#" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" title="Go back">Back</a>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#photosNJ" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Photos Noche Joven</a></li>
                <li><a href="#photosEJ">Photos Esp Joen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#videos">Videos</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- /navbar -->
    </div> <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="albums">  
            <!-- Here the albums are created through javascript (createAlbums.js) -->
        </ul>   

        <button type="button" id="loadMoreAlbums">More Albums...</button>   

    </div> <!-- /content -->
    <!-- <div id="fb-root"></div> -->

</div>


<div data-role="page" id="photosEJ" data-theme="a" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">
    <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/createFbAlbums2.js'></script>-->
    <div data-role="header" data-id="fixedNav" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Application Title</h1>
        <a href="#" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" title="Go back">Back</a>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#photosNJ">Photos Noche Joven</a></li>
                <li><a href="#photosEJ" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Photos Espacio Joven</a></li>
                <li><a href="#videos">Videos</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- /navbar -->
    </div> <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="albums2"> 
            <!-- Here the albums are created through javascript (createAlbums.js) -->
        </ul>       

        <button type="button" id="loadMoreAlbums2">More Albums...</button>      
    </div> <!-- /content -->
    <!-- <div id="fb-root"></div> -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you VERY VERY much if you decided to read till this far. ANY, absolutely ANY comment or idea on this one would be super valuable to me , so please if you have any thought share with me :)

**FIDDLER:** http://jsfiddle.net/lessisv/GW4PK/

Go to *Multimedia* and there i have 2 tabs *"Photos Noche Joven"* , *"Photos Espacio Joven"*. You can see that the first one is loading normally. Also if you go down you can see the *"More Albums"* button , that also works normally and make calls to the API. The problem is that when i go to *"Photos Espacio Joven"* , the call is not working for the reasons i described.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle please? It's quite some code.

Comment: Probably the FB object is initialised only once for this web page with the values of the first app.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer sir. However i dont really understand what you mean.. Could you please explain me what you mean by that and what solution would you recommend? Thank you again!

Comment: The FB object is inititialized only once for a web page in the FB.init. I do not know if it can be initialized again with different values e.g. the second page ID. Never heard of a web page using two different FB applications. Examine the values of the FB object.

Comment: Actually i am using the same application id , in both cases. Do you think that could be the problem? I mean i use the same appId in the init function.

Comment: I just created a new fb app , and got a new id. I am using this for the second page but sadly i get the same result.. No idea how could i fix it eh ?

Comment: It looks like that _#photosNJ_ is conflicting with _#photosEJ_. If you remove the code of _#photosNJ_, _#photosEJ_ works. I recommend you combine both codes in one. The problem is within re-executing the code again `window.fbAsyncInit` isn't running when you move to the other page.

Comment: The problem is that the last code is always executing.. Like is overriding the previous one. I tried combining the codes but still i cant fix it. I think that maybe i cant use fb.init twice like i do.. :

Comment: `connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` is being loaded twice, you need to check whether it has been loaded before loading it again.

Comment: Thank you @Omar ! I know i try to comment that line , but again i have the same problem. Actually i even tried to comment all the asychronous load of the SDK, the second time that is called : (function(d, s, id){..}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); but still it doesnt work... Pff i think we are very close , something is called twice that it shouldnt , but i cant understand what...

Comment: I do not think you can use the FB.init event twice. It is raised just once. Maybe you should move the album loading functionality to another event in order to use it repeatedly. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: but i do use the fb.init event many times , with the "More Albums" button that i have! Check the javascript! Its in the end , of the the fiddler i gave! When you hit the more albums button , you run fb.init again and runs like a charm. Problem is , it doesnt run , when i navigate to another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need `window.fbAsyncInit` in your `loadMoreAlbums` handlers. You define the same function earlier - that is enough.

Second,  you don't use `FB.init` many times - only once. Because it is defined inside `window.fbAsyncInit`, and that function is called by Facebook SDK when SDK is loaded. And there is a check whether the script is already loaded:

```
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
```

That means you load FB script once and init FB once.

The main thing is that you cannot init FB object (FB.init) in one scope (one of the "pageshow event" handlers) and then use FB.api in another scope (the other handler). That is why you get empty result.

There are several solutions you can try.

1.You can init FB every time the page changes.

Just check for FB object is present and call window.fbAsyncInit(). You could try quickly this solution by changing

```
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
```

to

```
if (d.getElementById(id)) {window.fbAsyncInit(); return;}
```

This is the ugly way.

2.You really should refactor your code.

Init FB on top level - not in the two handlers; create one handler - and call it when the page is changed. You can pass necessary parameters or use DOM elements data.

PS. A new handler for loadMoreAlbums is added every time the page changes. You switch to another album, go back and get two calls and double data, switch again and get triple data.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", '#photosNJ', function () {
   ...

    $("#loadMoreAlbums").click(function () {
        ...
    });
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a lot to say...

1. You do have to factor things to avoid creating your functions for each "page"
2. You don't have to call `FB.init` more than once, as the `fbAsyncInit` will be called only once, and the `FB.api` query to retrieve the albums won't be fired the next time you call `FB.init` (this is why you can't load the data of the second page)
3. Yes the more button works even if you have a `FB.init`, because your `FB.api` request is not inside the `fbAsyncInit` function
4. As your pages are public, you don't need to know if the user is connected or if he has accepted your app, so you can fire the `FB.api` just after the `FB.init`, but in other cases you would have to implement a `FB.login` function or at least a listener to the status change event to know if your user is connected, and then fire the requests
5. ...

If you want to look at one way to achieve all this, look at here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZES3X/